# Sklearn: How to write custom transformers for handling column names

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a pipeline for cleaning operations. I have written custom transformers for each operations for eg:

```
Class RemoveDuplicateRows(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
   def __init__(self):
     # init
     
   def fit(self, X, y):
     return self
     
  def transform(self, X, y):
     return X.drop_duplicates()

     
class RemoveDuplicateColumns(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
   def __init__(self):
     self.duplicate_column_names = list()
     
   def fit(self, X, y):
     self.duplicate_column_names_ = # logic_to_find_duplicate column names
        return self
     
  def transform(self, X, y):
     return X.drop(self.duplicate_column_names_, axis=1)

     
class FillOutliers(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
   def __init__(self):
     self.numeric_columns_ = list()
     
   def fit(self, X, y):
     self.numeric_columns_ = X_.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.tolist()
     # logic to find outliers using IQR
        return self
     
  def transform(self, X, y):
     # logic
     return X
```

Individually, they all running fine. But problem occurs, when I put them in pipeline, getting error as

```
steps = [
  ("remove_duplicate_rows", RemoveDuplicateRows()),
  ("remove_duplicate_columns", RemoveDuplicateColumns()),
  ("fill_outliers", FillOutliers()),
]

pipe.Pipeline(steps=steps) 

pipe.fit(X=df)

# saving the pipe

# loading the pipe

pipe.transform(X=df)

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has x elements, new values have y elements
```

My guess is say for eg I have 4 numerical columns in the dataframe and suppose `RemoveDuplicateColumns` removes 2 numerical columns from it but next `FillOutliers` still have learned 4 numerical columns and their column names.

Do I need to manually handle the column names in each transformers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you drop rows from `X` but not from `y`. This will cause trouble in later code when X and y is required to have the same number of rows.

If you provide code that can be run, I can investigate further, but this seems quite likely to me.

Comment: Hi Klops, Thanks for pointing about target. Issue resolved.